# System.NullReferenceException' occurred in worklight-windowsphone8.DLL and closes the application

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-runtime

On Windows Phone 8/8.1 navigator.camera.getPicture open photolibrary and call onSuccess callback function but same time it raise following error "'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in worklight-windowsphone8.DLL " closes the worklight application
--Scenerio
 Worklight 6.3.0 windowsphone8 enviornment new enviornment created. cordova 3.6
 on button click Windows Phone 8/8.1 photogallery is opened image is selected and photoalbum closes and I see the length in alert but same time raises the above error.

```
--code on button click
function onClickB(){
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 20,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });

function onSuccess(imageData) 
    {
       alert(imageData.length);--it gives me length Number
       var VarUsedtoSendToAdapter=imageData;
    }

    --OnVS Debug Console get 
    System.NullReferenceException' occurred in worklight-windowsphone8.DLL on Continue it closes the application
```

Comment: Can you provide something more meaningful to work with? Like a reproduction, and more information about your Worklight setup (version...), etc?

Comment: Code, add code. Not in the comment - edit the question

Comment: Hi Idan , Question has been edited.

Comment: The development team should reply soon.

Comment: We are trying on IBM MobileFirst studio - 6.3.0.00-20150214-1702 VS Professional 2013 Update 3 Target - Windows Phone 8.1 Lumia 930 , Exception details are System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IBM.Worklight.
   .responseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)}

Comment: I think you need to provide a visual studio project recreating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to recreate the issue.

Steps taken to recreate -

Code used -

```
function onClickB(){

        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 20,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
      });


    function onSuccess(imageData){
       alert(imageData.length);
       var VarUsedtoSendToAdapter=imageData;
    }

    function onFail(message){
       alert ("Failed because " + message);
    }

}
```

Trial 1:

Environment -

IBM MobileFirst studio - 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357
Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 2
Target - Windows Phone 8.0

Trial 2:

IBM MobileFirst studio - 6.3.0.00-20150214-1702
Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 2
Target - Windows Phone 8.0

Results (in both trials)-

1) Device 1 - Nokia Lumia 1520 - WP 8.1 update 1

```
   Library launches, we select file , length is alerted. 
   The message -"System.NullReferenceException' occurred in worklight-windowsphone8.DLL" does not appear
```

2) Device 2 -  HTC 8x (Windows 8.0

```
    Library launches, we select file , length is alerted. 
   The message -"System.NullReferenceException' occurred in worklight-windowsphone8.DLL" does not appear
```

Tested with multiple images of different file sizes from album and from camera roll and the results are same.

Questions:

1) Is the issue occuring with a project that was freshly created on Mobile First 6.3 studio?

2) Is the project migrated to 6.3 ? If so, can you please try removing the WP 8 environment and adding it again?

Comment: Yes this project migrated to 6.3 and then added this feature we removed the WP 8 environment and ceated new env again. but getting same 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in worklight-windowsphone8.DLL

Comment: The exception "System.Net.WebException" raised may not be related to the Cordova plugin. Do you see the exception only when the camera plugin is used ? 
 A recreatable test case will help a lot.

Comment: Following is the line of code where it stop and on proceed it close the application.    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {

            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
               System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        } and detail error is  "Object reference not set to an inst of an object. at IBM.Worklight.responseCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>"

Comment: Does this error occur only when using the Camera plugin? or does it appear other times as well?
Can you provide a recreatable sample? We have tried multiple times and are not able to recreate the issue.

Comment: Yes this exception is raised only when calling camera plugin on WP8.1 Update 1 this exception raised by WL does this exception is not self explanatory what could be the possible reason ? I tried a simple project and did not find this error. only difference is that I did not connect to worklight server.

Comment: We can take a look if you provide your WP8 project on which the issue is consistently reproducible.

Comment: Any news about the issue ? We are experiencing the same issue here. Here is our crash stack : https://justpaste.it/sxh4

Comment: @WiPhone, are you trying the same Cordova plugin? Or is it a totally different usecase?

Comment: We are using also the camera plugin for multiple attachements,
The issue/crash does occur after attaching multiple images. Initially we thought it was related to the memory and camera plugin, but when reading the crash stack, we feel that it's related to some background callbacks in Worklight lib

Comment: We were not able to recreate it the last time we tried - details already updated in the answer. Can you provide your sample, so that we can take a look?